# Array initialization at runtime

Tags: c, arrays

[code link](http://ideone.com/6hafJF)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    int arr[c];
    arr[5] = 0;
    printf("%d",arr[5]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is 0

How is it that at runtime it is taking the array number ? Is it a new feature ?

Comment: Is a feature added last century "new" ?

Comment: Is it because you already initialized it? because if you were doing something like printf( "%d" ,arr[ 4 ]); you would get an error

Answer (score 4):

This is a variable length array. They were introduced in the 1999 revision of the C standard.

Sadly support for them came in slowly, so much that the 2011 revision made them an optional feature (but they are still standardized) <sup>1</sup>.

Despite looking cool, they have a major caveat. They can cause you to overflow the call stack if the size is "too big". As such, care needs to be taken when using them.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Some compiler vendors were resistant, so it was made optional to appease them. Microsoft is an entire case study of this.</sub>

Comment: The reason for making it optional is because the "support for them came in slowly"? Any reference?

Comment: @P.P. - That's the feeling I get. Some compiler vendors were resistant, so it was made optional to appease them. Microsoft is an entire case study of this.

Answer (score 1):

This feature (*Variable length array*) has been introduced in [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). But currently this still is a compiler-dependent behavior. Some compiler(like gcc) supports it. Some(like msvc) doesn't.

BTW, `arr[5]` in your code, is out of range. Last element should be `arr[4]`.

Comment: This is standard C. Not an extension (although it is compiler dependent since Microsoft were very slow ti implement C99)

Comment: @StoryTeller I was not aware of that. I did some digging after see your comment, and update link in my answer. :-)

Answer (score -1):

don't be confused in (static/fixed memory allocation) & (dynamic memory allocation) concepts :)

*Let me clear your concept bro*.

Relevant to following question,

```
                           C supports two type of array.
```

1.**Static Array** - are allocated memory at "COMPILE TIME".

2.**Dynamic Array** -  are allocated memory at "RUN TIME".

**Ques.**   how to determine if an Array is static or dynamic?

**Ans.** 
       Array declaration syntax:-

```
         int array_Name[size];     //size defines the size of block of memory for an array;
```

So, coming to the point-->

Point 1.     if size is given at compile time to array, it's a "Static Memory Allocation". It is also called "fixed size memory allocation" because size is never changed. **It's the LIMITATION of ARRAY in C.**

ex. 
  `int arr[10];                         //10 is size of arr which is staticly defined
    int brr[] = {1000, 2, 37, 755, 3};  //size is equal to the no. of values initilizes with.`

point 2.  If size is given at compile time to array, it's a Dynamic Memory Allocation. 
           It is achieved by malloc() function defined in stdlib.h .

Now, its's the clarification of your code :-

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
        // your code goes here
        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;
        int c;
        c = a + b;             //c is calculated at run time
        int arr[c];           //Compilor awaiting for the value of c which is given at run time but,
        arr[5] = 0;           //here arr is allocated the size of 5 at static(compile) time which is never be change further whether it is compile time in next statements or run time.
        printf("%d",arr[5]);  
        return 0;
    }
```

So, array(of size 5)  holds value 0 at arr[5].
and ,other array indexes still show Garbage Values.

Hoping, you'll be satisfy with this solution to your problem :)